# Chrome app not saving data to local storage

Tags: google-chrome, storage, local

I am developing a chrome app that needs to save some data to the local storage and retrieve it afterwards.

I follow the guides on the Chrome storage API
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

and have a simple code to save data:

```
function saveCurrentPort()
{

    chrome.storage.local.set({'last_port': connectedPortPath}, function() {
              // Notify that we saved.
              writeConsole('JS last port saved:' + connectedPortPath );
              if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
                    alert('JS An error occurred: ' + chrome.extension.lastError.message);
                }
            });

}
```

After calling this with valid data, nothing gets saved in the local storage. Looking into the Resource tab in the developer tools window for my App I see no entry in the Local Storage section (nor in the Session Storage).
Of course, attempting to retrieve this data fails because the data isn't found.
This should be straight forward but simply doesn't work for me.
I run the App locally in developer mode.

Looking for other questions here I didn't see a case like this.

Any idea why it isn't working? am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I think you used "permissions" as advised?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the "storage" permission to your `manifest.json`?

```
   {
        "name": "My extension",
        ...
        "permissions": [
          "storage"
        ],
        ...
      }
```

Plus, `alert()` is not allowed from chrome app.
I think there must be more errors. you might need to fix it first.

Comment: Hi. Yes, the permission is set of course in the manifest.json. I followed the instructions for this API. Your are right about the alert but it doesn't change the issue since it never gets to the alert, lastError is not set.

Comment: Did you check if `saveCurrentPort` is actually called?

Comment: Yes. The line  writeConsole('JS last port saved:' + connectedPortPath );   writes a proper entry in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

Besides permission you need to put the value of 'last_port'

```
var last_port_var= 'last_port';

var portObj= {};

portObj[last_port_var] = connectedPortPath;
```

Now set the value by object:

```
chrome.storage.local.set(portObj, function() {
     //code goes here....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. I tried your suggestion in the past from another post I have seen and again now. It still doesn't work. Plus, according to the API documentation the original code should have worked too.